# Find changes (new rows, deleted rows, updated rows) between two excel files

Tags: microsoft-excel, version-control

We have an excel file with two sheets (`oldSheet` and `newSheet`) both of them containing the following columns **(A: "barcode", B: "price", C: "discount")**.

The `newSheet` is an updated version of the `oldSheet` which means new rows/products have been added (new barcodes), prices and/or discounts are updated for certain barcodes, rows/barcodes are removed (`barcode` of the oldSheet not found in the newSheet).

I want to create a third sheet called **outputSheet** which combines the oldSheet and newSheet while highlighting the removed rows based on the barcode from the oldSheet with **Red**, the new barcods which have been added to the newSheet with **Green**, the modified rows (same barcode in oldSheet and newSheet) but either `price` or `discount` columns have been modified with **Yellow**

Since my account is new, I can't post images so I added links

**oldSheet:**
[oldSheetScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zC5E8.png)

**newSheet:**
[newSheetScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/658Nw.png)

**outputSheet would like something like this:**
[outputSheetScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4m5ZZ.png)

Red Rows: barcodes found in `oldSheet` but not in the `newSheet`.

Yellow Rows: barcodes found in both sheets but with different price or discount values.

Green Rows: new barcodes added to the `newSheet` and doesn't exist in the `oldSheet`.

the sequence is not important as long as it shows the added, removed and modified rows/products

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a query on both tables with Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

I named them 'old' and 'new' such that I have this in the Power Query Editor:

[image]

Now in Power Query, use Home>Combine>Merge Queries>Merge Queries As New and configure it like this:

[image]

Then, click the double-arrow at the top right of the 'new' column:

[image]

Accept the default, such that you have this:

[image]

Now use Add Column>Custom Column like this:
[image]

This is the formula:

```
Replacer.ReplaceValue([barcode],null,[new.barcode])
```

Now select barcode and new.barcode, right-click and Remove those columns. Rename barcode.1 to barcode and drag the column to the far left.

Add a new custom column called status with this formula:

```
if [price] = null then "New" else 
if [new.price] = null then "Removed" else
if [new.price]<>[price] or [new.quantity]<>[quantity] then 
"Updated" else "No change"
```

Now remove the price and quantity columns (select, right-click, remove), then rename new.price and new.quantity to price and quantity respectively.

At this point you should have this:

[image]

Use Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the workbook.

Use Table Design>Table Styles to change the table style of the query result to 'None'.

Select all the data rows:

[image]

Use Home>Styles>Conditional Formatting>New Rule>Use a formula to determine which cells to format to create three rules for each interesting value in the status column:

[image]

Pay particular attention to the $s in the cell references.

Seems like a lot of steps to go through each time... BUT, if you save this query and make sure that your "new" and "old" data are always in the same Named Tables when you receive an update, you can just refresh this query to see which rows are new, removed or changed.

Please edit / insert steps into the query appropriately if I have missed anything.

Comment: Thank you so much!